# How can I run bash script in the background?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, background-process

I'm learning bash scripting and I just made a short-project to notify me (with notify-send) when my battery is low or charged.

I'd like some suggestions of how can I run this script without showing the terminal.
My idea is to add it in "Startup Applications" software to run when I boot the system, but I don't want to show the terminal, just to run in the background.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a systemd service.

You could create a file (as sudo) with you favorite editor (nano, vim etc) like:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/myexecuteable.service
```

It should contain at least the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=start my executable after multi-user target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/my/executable

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To ensure that the service will start after reboot execute:
`sudo systemctl enable myexecutable.service`

That service will run continously if you bash has some kind of loop. If that executable has some output (use "logger for that in a bash file) you can check it any time using `journalctl -u myexecutable.service`

Comment: That won't work with `notify-send`. At least not without some fiddling around (see answers here on unix.SE relating to `notify-send` and `cron`)

Comment: Right, You'll have to incorporate XAuthority and a user in the bash.

Comment: I'll try it, first, if I can't make it functional, I'll try cron. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2):

A script may be run in the background from the command line like this:

```bsh
$ ./myscript.sh &
```

In other words, append  `&` to the command.

You've said you want to run this script "without showing the termial". I think there are two ways to do this:

1. create a `systemd` service - as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616234/286615)
2. start the script as a `cron` job when the system boots:

#### To set up a `cron` job, you will need to create a new `crontab` entry.

To do this, open a terminal, and type the following command:

```bsh
$ crontab -e
```

This will open your `crontab` in an editor (`nano` is a good choice for editor). When you are in the editor, add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```
@reboot /home/user/myscript.sh & >> /home/user/myscript.log 2>&1
```

Where `/home/user/myscript.sh` is the **full path** to your script file. Any output from your script will be **redirected** to the file at `/home/user/myscript.log`. Be sure to check this logfile for any error messages.

Save the file ( `^ o` ) if using `nano`, and exit the editor ( `^ x`).

Some things to remember:

1. Make sure `myscript.sh` is **executable**.
2. If you use any commands in `myscript.sh`, make sure the system knows where to find them - i.e. use a **full path** to the command, or declare a PATH in your script.

Let us know if you have further questions (post a comment) & we'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you for answering.I'll try first the systemd service. If I cant manage to do this, I'l try cron.